# Break a table in half by columns and put it in below mentioned order

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this :

| cat1 | priceA | priceB | type1 | cat2 | costA | costB | type2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 55 | 70 | X | CAN | 25 | 15 | Z |
| UK | 30 | 26 | Y | IND | 20 | 20 | Z |
| NZ | 38 | 36 | Z | GER | 40 | 25 | Y |
| USA | 47 | 49 | Z | AUS | 60 | 15 | X |

I need to get it like below without using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

| cat3 | totalA | totalB | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | 55 | 70 | X |
| UK | 30 | 26 | Y |
| NZ | 38 | 36 | Z |
| USA | 47 | 49 | Z |
| CAN | 25 | 15 | Z |
| IND | 20 | 20 | Z |
| GER | 40 | 25 | Y |
| AUS | 60 | 15 | X |

I don't have permission to create procedures so no `PL/SQL`. Any ways to do it without using the following in `Oracle`?

```
select cat1, priceA, priceB, type1
UNION ALL
select cat2,costA,costB,type2
```

EDIT:

for two column table like this :

| cat1 | cat2 |
| --- | --- |
| UK | CAN |
| UK | IND |
| NZ | GER |
| USA | AUS |

To get this :

| cat3 |
| --- |
| UK |
| UK |
| NZ |
| USA |
| CAN |
| IND |
| GER |
| AUS |

I can use this:

```
SELECT 
   cat3 
FROM 
(
    SELECT cat1, cat2 AS cat3
    WHERE <conditions>
) T UNPIVOT (cat3 FOR COL IN (cat1, cat2))
```

But how to do it for multiple columns ?

Comment: And why can't you use UNION ALL, is it homework?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because the original table is an inner join of multiple tables and it makes the query look huge and cumbersome and would probably also affect performance if we double the number of inner joins

Comment: why the down vote ?

Comment: I would guess that the downvote is because your question is hard to understand. In a comment you said *" Because the original table is an inner join of multiple tables '*. So your "original table" is actually a query? You should post a question which accurately reflects the problem you're trying to solve. Otherwise people will think you're tying to solve a trivial problem and downvote, or waste their time posting a suggestion which doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with a `cross join` and end with `case..when` statements as below :

```
with tab( cat1 , priceA , priceB , type1 , 
          cat2 , costA  , costB  , type2 ) as
(
 select 'UK' , 55, 70 , 'X' , 'CAN' , 25 , 15 , 'Z' from dual union all    
 select 'UK' , 30, 26 , 'Y' , 'IND' , 20 , 20 , 'Z' from dual union all    
 select 'NZ' , 38, 36 , 'Z' , 'GER' , 40 , 25 , 'Y' from dual union all    
 select 'USA', 47, 49 , 'Z' , 'AUS' , 60 , 15 , 'X' from dual
), tab2 as
(
select t1.cat1 , t1.priceA , t1.priceB , t1.type1,
       t2.cat2 , t2.costA  , t2.costB  , t2.type2, 
       row_number() over ( partition by t1.cat1, t1.type1 order by t1.cat1, t1.type1 ) rn
  from tab t1
  cross join tab t2
), tab3 as
(
select t.*, mod(rn,2) as r2
  from tab2 t
) 
select distinct
       ( case when r2 = 1 then cat1 else cat2 end ) as cat1,
       ( case when r2 = 1 then priceA else costA end ) as priceA,
       ( case when r2 = 1 then priceB else costB end ) as priceB,
       ( case when r2 = 1 then type1 else type2 end ) as type1
  from tab3;

CAT1 PRICEA PRICEB  TYPE1
AUS  60     15      X
UK   55     70      X
NZ   38     36      Z
UK   30     26      Y
USA  47     49      Z
IND  20     20      Z
CAN  25     15      Z
GER  40     25      Y
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/FOGLS32679)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to unpivot is:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then cat1 else cat2 end) as cat,
       (case when n.n = 1 then priceA else costA end) as totalB,
       (case when n.n = 1 then priceB else costB end) as totalB,
       (case when n.n = 1 then type1 else typ2 end) as type
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n from dual union all select 2 from dual) n;
```

I don't know if this violates the rather weird restriction on `union all`.  But this can also be phrased as:

```
from t cross join
     (select rownum as n from t where rownum <= 2) n;
```

In Oracle 12C, a lateral join is the way to go (although this still requires a `union all`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (select t.cat1 as cat3, t.priceA as totalA, t.priceB as totalB, t.type1 as type union all
      select t.cat2, t.costA, t.costB, t.type2
     ) v;
```

And finally, `union all` would be fine with a CTE:

```
with cte as (
      . . .
     )
select t.cat1 as cat3, t.priceA as totalA, t.priceB as totalB, t.type1 as type
from cte t
union all
select t.cat2, t.costA, t.costB, t.type2
from cte t;
```

Oracle will materialize the CTE if the optimizer things that is the best approach, removing your issues with performance.

Comment: In the first method, I put the query which gives the result as the table in place of t like: select (case when n.n = 1 then t.cat1 else t.cat2 end) as cat,....from (select .....) t  cross join (select .....) n; But it gives the error : missing expression

Comment: @katipra . . . "2" as missing.

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to do further select and group by on the resulting output.

Comment: @katipra . . . I have no idea what that comment is supposed to mean.  The result is the result set; you can use it in a view, CTE, or subquery just like any other result set.